# How do I change the color of scatter plot in bokeh real time?

Tags: python, bokeh, scatter-plot

I'm new in Bokeh, and I'm trying to construct an interactive scatter plot. 
In this plot, I would like to change the p-value cut-off and, then, change the colors according to the rule (if FC < 0, the dots are blue; if FC > 0, dots are red.
I've tried:

```
from bokeh.plotting import ColumnDataSource, figure, output_file, show, curdoc
from bokeh.models import BoxSelectTool, LassoSelectTool,CustomJS, Slider
from bokeh.transform import linear_cmap
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot, column, row
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

fc = np.random.uniform(0, 4, 1000)
p_value = np.random.uniform(0,1,1000)

df = pd.DataFrame([fc, p_value], ['FC', 'pvalue']).transpose()
df['log2(fc)'] = np.log2(df['FC'])
df['-log10(p)'] = -np.log10(df['pvalue'])

output_file("df.html")   
y = df['-log10(p)']
x = df['log2(fc)']
col = np.where(y> -np.log10(0.5), np.where( x>-0,  np.where( x<0, '#606060','#E4001B'), '#6194BC'), '#606060' )
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
    x=df['log2(fc)'],
    y=df['-log10(p)'],
    pvalue=df['pvalue'],
    FC = df['log2(fc)'],
    color = col))

TOOLTIPS = [
    ("FC", "@FC"),
    ("pvalue", "@pvalue")
]


TOOLS="hover,crosshair,pan,wheel_zoom,zoom_in,zoom_out,box_zoom,undo,redo,reset,tap,save,box_select,poly_select,lasso_select,"
p = figure(plot_width=500, plot_height=500, tooltips=TOOLTIPS, 
           title="test", tools=TOOLS)

p.circle('x', 'y', size=5, source=source, alpha = 0.5, fill_color = 'color', line_color='color')
p.xaxis.axis_label = "log2(FC)"
p.yaxis.axis_label = "-log10(p)"
p.background_fill_color = "#fafafa"

p_slider = Slider(start=0.0, end=5, step=.01, title="p_value")

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source,plot=p, color_mapper = col, pvalue=p_slider),
                    code="""
    const data = source.data;
    var P = pvalue.value;
    const x = df['p_value']
    const y = df['log2(fc)']
    source.change.emit();
""")



p_slider.js_on_change('value', callback)

layout = row(
    p,
    column(p_slider),
)


show(layout)
```

Despite this approach show me the bar to control the p-value, I'm not getting to control the bar, neither change the colors according to p-value...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: In your callback, you have to actually go in and modify `data['color']`. This means looping over `data['y']` and setting `data['color']` accordingly.

Comment: To expand on the above comment: `CustomJS` callbacks execute *Javascript code, in the browser*. Python things like Pandas dataframes do not exist there, at all. If you want to be able to run real Python code for callbacks, that is what theh Bokeh server is for.

Comment: @BallpointBen thank you for the reply. I've been trying several options to handle that. But I'm still lost (maybe because I don't have any experience with Java language). Do you have any tips to help me?

Comment: @GuilhermeReis the examples here are a good starting point https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html